# How to find table border lines in pdf using PDFBox?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to find table border lines in pdf. I used `PrintTextLocations` class of pdfBox to make words. Now I am looking to find the coordinates of different lines that form the table. I tried using `org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer`, but I am unable to find any character/graphic containing those lines. I tried two ways:

First:

```
Graphics g = null;
Dimension d = new Dimension();
d.setSize(700, 700);
PageDrawer pageDrawer = new PageDrawer();
pageDrawer.drawPage(g, myPage, d);
```

It gave me null pointer exception. So secondly, I tried to override `processStream` function, but I am unable to get any stroke. Kindly help me out. I am open in using any other library which gives me coordinates of the lines in the table. And another quick question, what kind of objects are those table border lines in pdfbox? Are these graphics or are these characters?

Here is the link to the sample pdf I am trying to parse:
http://stats.bls.gov/news.release/pdf/empsit.pdf
and trying to get the table lines on page number 8.

**Edit** :  I faced another problem, while parsing this pdf's page number 1, I am unable to get any lines as the `pathIterator` in `printPath()` function is empty, although `strokePath()` function is called for each line. How to work with this pdf?

Comment: @Jongware Find the link in the edited post. Thanks

Comment: Which PDFBox version do you use? In particular, is it some 1.8.X version or the current 2.0.0 release candidate? Concerning your first piece of code: As your set `Graphics g = null` and then do `pageDrawer.drawPage(g, myPage, d)`, a `NullPointerException` is to be expected. You obviously have to provide a graphics context to draw on...

Comment: My approach was to get the graphics of the page as PDPage does not provide any graphics. I was thinking of calling the `drawPage` funtion and get a graphics object which might contain the line graphics.

Comment: And I am using 1.8X version of pdfBox

Comment: Concerning the other document cpid1511.pdf - all those vector graphics operations are from the table... but those operations did not merely paint the *lines*, most of them actually painted the *letters* of the table content! (Usually you draw text using text operations referencing fonts which contain the exact drawing operations, but here the letters directly were drawn using vector graphics...)

Comment: @mkl Oh yes, I was checking with all the pdf's, and didn't know that this table was actually a vector graphic. That's why I removed the edit. Thanks anyways. But I faced another problem, while parsing [this pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9q9YK3qNDvxX0lzcGVuejRRbHc/view?usp=sharing)'s page number 1, I am unable to get any lines as the `pathIterator` in `printPath()` function is empty, although `strokePath()` function is called for each line. How to work with this pdf?

Comment: There was a little bug, see the edit in my answer. Bugfix: in PrintPaths.processStream one must use PDPage.findCropBox, not PDPage.getCropBox. With that in place you get the lines for h8.pdf, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the 1.8.* versions PDFBox parsing capabilities had been implemented in a not very generic way, in particular the `OperatorProcessor` implementations were tightly associated with specific parser classes, e.g. the implementations dealing with path drawing operations assumed to interact with a `PageDrawer` instance.

Thus, unless one wanted to copy & paste all those `OperatorProcessor` classes with minute changes, one had to derive from such a specific parser class.

In your case, therefore, we also will derive our parser from `PageDrawer`, after all we *are* interested in path drawing operations:

```
public class PrintPaths extends PageDrawer
{
    //
    // constructor
    //
    public PrintPaths() throws IOException
    {
        super();
    }

    //
    // method overrides for mere path observation
    //
    // ignore text
    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) { }

    // ignore bitmaps
    @Override
    public void drawImage(Image awtImage, AffineTransform at) { }

    // ignore shadings
    @Override
    public void shFill(COSName shadingName) throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void processStream(PDPage aPage, PDResources resources, COSStream cosStream) throws IOException
    {
        PDRectangle cropBox = aPage.findCropBox();
        this.pageSize = cropBox.createDimension();
        super.processStream(aPage, resources, cosStream);
    }

    @Override
    public void fillPath(int windingRule) throws IOException
    {
        printPath();
        System.out.printf("Fill; windingrule: %s\n\n", windingRule);
        getLinePath().reset();
    }

    @Override
    public void strokePath() throws IOException
    {
        printPath();
        System.out.printf("Stroke; unscaled width: %s\n\n", getGraphicsState().getLineWidth());
        getLinePath().reset();
    }

    void printPath()
    {
        GeneralPath path = getLinePath();
        PathIterator pathIterator = path.getPathIterator(null);

        double x = 0, y = 0;
        double coords[] = new double[6];
        while (!pathIterator.isDone()) {
            switch (pathIterator.currentSegment(coords)) {
            case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                System.out.printf("Move to (%s %s)\n", coords[0], fixY(coords[1]));
                x = coords[0];
                y = coords[1];
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                double width = getEffectiveWidth(coords[0] - x, coords[1] - y);
                System.out.printf("Line to (%s %s), scaled width %s\n", coords[0], fixY(coords[1]), width);
                x = coords[0];
                y = coords[1];
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                System.out.printf("Quad along (%s %s) and (%s %s)\n", coords[0], fixY(coords[1]), coords[2], fixY(coords[3]));
                x = coords[2];
                y = coords[3];
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                System.out.printf("Cubic along (%s %s), (%s %s), and (%s %s)\n", coords[0], fixY(coords[1]), coords[2], fixY(coords[3]), coords[4], fixY(coords[5]));
                x = coords[4];
                y = coords[5];
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                System.out.println("Close path");
            }
            pathIterator.next();
        }
    }

    double getEffectiveWidth(double dirX, double dirY)
    {
        if (dirX == 0 && dirY == 0)
            return 0;
        Matrix ctm = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
        double widthX = dirY;
        double widthY = -dirX;
        double widthXTransformed = widthX * ctm.getValue(0, 0) + widthY * ctm.getValue(1, 0);
        double widthYTransformed = widthX * ctm.getValue(0, 1) + widthY * ctm.getValue(1, 1);
        double factor = Math.sqrt((widthXTransformed*widthXTransformed + widthYTransformed*widthYTransformed) / (widthX*widthX + widthY*widthY));
        return getGraphicsState().getLineWidth() * factor;
    }
}
```

*([PrintPaths.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/PrintPaths.java))*

As we do not want to actually *draw* the page but merely extract the paths which *would be drawn*, we have to strip down the `PageDrawer` like this.

This sample parser outputs path drawing operations to show how to do it. Obviously you can instead collect them for automatized processing...

You can use the parser like this:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
List<?> allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
int i = 7; // page 8

System.out.println("\n\nPage " + (i+1));
PrintPaths printPaths = new PrintPaths();

PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
PDStream contents = page.getContents();
if (contents != null)
{
    printPaths.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
}
```

*([ExtractPaths.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/ExtractPaths.java))*

The output is:

```
Page 8
Move to (35.92070007324219 724.6490478515625)
Line to (574.72998046875 724.6490478515625), scaled width 0.5981000089123845
Stroke; unscaled width: 5.981

Move to (35.92070007324219 694.4660034179688)
Line to (574.72998046875 694.4660034179688), scaled width 0.5981000089123845
Stroke; unscaled width: 5.981

Move to (292.2610168457031 468.677001953125)
Line to (292.8590087890625 468.677001953125), scaled width 512.9430076434463
Stroke; unscaled width: 5129.43

Move to (348.9360046386719 468.677001953125)
Line to (349.53399658203125 468.677001953125), scaled width 512.9430076434463
Stroke; unscaled width: 5129.43

Move to (405.6090087890625 468.677001953125)
Line to (406.2070007324219 468.677001953125), scaled width 512.9430076434463
Stroke; unscaled width: 5129.43

Move to (462.281982421875 468.677001953125)
Line to (462.8799743652344 468.677001953125), scaled width 512.9430076434463
Stroke; unscaled width: 5129.43

Move to (518.9549560546875 468.677001953125)
Line to (519.553955078125 468.677001953125), scaled width 512.9430076434463
Stroke; unscaled width: 5129.43

Move to (35.92070007324219 725.447998046875)
Line to (574.72998046875 725.447998046875), scaled width 0.5981000089123845
Stroke; unscaled width: 5.981

Move to (35.92070007324219 212.5050048828125)
Line to (574.72998046875 212.5050048828125), scaled width 0.5981000089123845
Stroke; unscaled width: 5.981
```

Quite peculiar: The vertical lines actually are drawn as very short (ca 0.6 units) very thick (ca 513 units) horizontal lines...

Comment: May I ask the meaning of Scaled Width?

Comment: The "unscaled width" here simply is the line width value in the Graphics state. But this needs not be the width you eventually perceive in the output because just like all other content lines also are subject to the current transformation matrix. The "scaled width" value here is an attempt to calculate the width you will eventually perceive in the output. As the transformation may not merely scale but actually also rotate and shear, the method `getEffectiveWidth` calculating this value is more than a mere scalar multiplication.