# How to detect the horizontal lines and their location in a PDF page

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

How to detect the horizontal lines and their location in a PDF page using PDFBox version 3.0.

[Horizontal lines in PDFBox version1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409283/how-to-find-table-border-lines-in-pdf-using-pdfbox/72069197#72069197)

I tried to follow the above link and implement the solution but, a lot has changed since then, so it is difficult to implement the above solution.

I am unable to upload a sample PDF as it is confidential but, the scenarios include horizontal table border lines, lines below the text - single and double lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931422/pdfbox-2-0-2-calling-of-pagedrawer-processpage-method-caught-exceptions

Comment: Amit, have you been able to find the lines in your PDF using the mechanisms from [@Tilman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38933039/1729265) and [this follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223836/1729265)?

Comment: @mkl , I have been able to read the horizontal lines from the PDF page and their location. Unfortunate, I am seeing a weird behaviour with PDFBox, it is splitting the numbers in two parts(not all of them though) like for example 25,000 to 2 and 5,000 when I apply sortToPosition true. Any idea around this behavior?

Comment: I'm not aware of ever having observed something like that. Please share enough code and an example PDF to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: @mkl I have opened a question for the same, as it required me to put more details and the comment section did not allow me. link - [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093362/pdbbox-number-split-when-setting-the-setsortbyposition-to-true)

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately without the PDF. Without the PDF all we can do is speculate and guess.

Answer (score 0):

@Tilman Hausherr Thank you for refering the link to implement the horizontal line detection. I am successfully able to indetify the horizontal lines and their location.
[Line detection and location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931422/pdfbox-2-0-2-calling-of-pagedrawer-processpage-method-caught-exceptions)

Comment: glad it works, but then it's obviously a duplicate, so the better solution would be to upvote that one and delete your question. Or share your code if it is different or better than the one there.