# PDBBox number split when setting the setSortByPosition to true

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to extract the text from the PDF document, I have inherited the PDFTextStripper as my use-case requied me to extract the text with more information not only the text part of it.

```
public class PDFBoxToTextBox extends PDFTextStripper {
    
    private StringBuilder notHorizontalOriented;


    public StringBuilder getNotHorizontalOriented() {
        return notHorizontalOriented;
    }

    public void setNotHorizontalOriented(StringBuilder notHorizontalOriented) {
        this.notHorizontalOriented = notHorizontalOriented;
    }

    public PDFBoxToTextBox() throws IOException {
        super();
        this.notHorizontalOriented = new StringBuilder();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static String getTextBloks(InputStream in, Integer pageNum) {
        try {
            byte[] targetArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
            PDDocument document;
            document = Loader.loadPDF(targetArray);
            PDPage doc = document.getPage(pageNum - 1);
            String page_height = String.valueOf(doc.getMediaBox().getHeight());
            String page_width = String.valueOf(doc.getMediaBox().getWidth());

            // Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
            PDFBoxToTextBox pdfStripper = new PDFBoxToTextBox();
            pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            //pdfStripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(false);
            pdfStripper.setDropThreshold(0.5f);
            pdfStripper.setIndentThreshold(.5f);
            pdfStripper.setLineSeparator("\n");
            pdfStripper.setWordSeparator("\t");
            System.out.println("Line seperator ::" + pdfStripper.getWordSeparator() + "::");

            // Retrieving text from PDF document
            pdfStripper.setStartPage(pageNum);
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(pageNum);
            // System.out.println(pdfStripper.getTextMatrix());
            String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
            System.out.println(text);
            List tBlocks = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String w : text.split("\\|")) {
                tBlocks.add(w);
                // System.out.println(w);
            }
            LineCatcher lineCatcher = new LineCatcher(doc);
            for(Map line :lineCatcher.getAllHorizontalPath(doc)){
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(line);
                tBlocks.add(json);
            }
            Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            // Closing the document
            document.close();
            result.put("page_width", page_width);
            result.put("page_height", page_height);
            result.put("text_blocks", tBlocks);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result);
            System.out.println("NOT horizontal tex : "+ pdfStripper.getNotHorizontalOriented().toString());
            System.out.println("JSON to Return");
            System.out.println(json);
            return json;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    private int getTextOrientation(TextPosition text) {
        Matrix m = text.getTextMatrix().clone();
        m.concatenate(text.getFont().getFontMatrix());
        int angle = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m.getShearY(), m.getScaleY())));
        return angle;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDropThreshold(float dropThresholdValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setDropThreshold(dropThresholdValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void setIndentThreshold(float indentThresholdValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setIndentThreshold(indentThresholdValue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeWordSeparator() throws IOException {
        output.write(" | ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeLineSeparator() throws IOException {
        output.write(" | ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        // ("TextBlock", ["x", "y", "w", "h", "text", "bold", "font_style","data_type"])
        Map<String, String> textBlock = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String prevBaseFont = "";
        String x = String.valueOf(textPositions.get(0).getXDirAdj());
        String y = String.valueOf(textPositions.get(0).getYDirAdj());
        String w = String.valueOf(textPositions.get(0).getWidth());
        String h = String.valueOf(textPositions.get(0).getHeightDir());
        int rotation = 0;
        Map<Float, List> charHeightMap = new HashMap<Float, List>();
        for (TextPosition position : textPositions) {
            if (charHeightMap.containsKey(position.getHeightDir())) {
                charHeightMap.get(position.getHeightDir()).add(position.getUnicode());
            } else {
                List<String> chars = new ArrayList<String>();
                chars.add(position.getUnicode());
                charHeightMap.put(position.getHeightDir(), chars);
            }
        }
        Float maxHeight = null;
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (Float ht : charHeightMap.keySet()) {
            if (charHeightMap.get(ht).size() > maxSize) {
                maxHeight = ht;
            }
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder fbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (TextPosition position : textPositions) {
            // if (position.getHeightDir() != maxHeight) {
            // continue;
            // }
            position.getRotation();
            String baseFont = position.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontName();
            if (baseFont != null && !baseFont.equals(prevBaseFont)) {
                // fbuilder.append('[').append(baseFont).append(']');
                fbuilder.append(baseFont);
                prevBaseFont = baseFont;
            }
            builder.append(position.getUnicode());
        }
        // System.out.println(rotation);
        // System.out.println(textPositions.get(0));
        Float wid = textPositions.get(textPositions.size() - 1).getXDirAdj() - textPositions.get(0).getXDirAdj();
        String font = fbuilder.toString();
        textBlock.put("text", builder.toString());
        textBlock.put("font", font);
        Boolean bold = true ? font.toLowerCase().contains("bold") : false;
        textBlock.put("bold", bold.toString());
        textBlock.put("x", x);
        textBlock.put("y", y);
        textBlock.put("w", wid.toString());
        textBlock.put("h", h);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(textBlock);
        writeString(json);
    }

    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {

        java.awt.Composite com;
        Color col;
        // System.out.println(this.getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode());
        System.out.println(text);
        System.out.println(this.getTextOrientation(text));
        switch (this.getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode()) {
        case FILL:
            if (this.getTextOrientation(text) == 0 || this.getTextOrientation(text) == 90) {
                super.processTextPosition(text);
            } else {
                this.notHorizontalOriented.append(text.getUnicode());
            }
            break;
        case STROKE:
            if (this.getTextOrientation(text) == 0 || this.getTextOrientation(text) == 90) {
                super.processTextPosition(text);

            } else {
                System.out.println(text.getUnicode() + ", X translate : "
                        + this.getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix().getShearX() + ", Y translate : "
                        + this.getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix().getTranslateY() + ", angle: "
                        + this.getTextOrientation(text));
                this.notHorizontalOriented.append(text.getUnicode());
            }
            break;
        case NEITHER:
            System.out.println(this.getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingJavaComposite().toString());
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(this.getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingJavaComposite().toString());
            System.out.println(this.getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingColor().getColorSpace().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot upload the PDF file, but I have included the image(cropped) to understand the text layout and associated values.
[image: PDF snippet as image]

There are two issues that I am facing now:

1. Some of the numerical value is getting split, in the image value *2,020,735* is getting split as *2* and *,020,735* two separate text blocks. When I set the sortByPosition to false I am getting the correct numerical values but, I need the sortByPosition set to true
2. The orientation angle is *90* in this case for the text in PDF which is surprising, as all the text is horizontal as displayed in the image above

I am not sure when I am going wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible to say why this very specific behavior occurs without checking the very specific pdf.

Comment: That being said, though, you appear to think that `writeString` is only called for complete words (or otherwise connected character groups). While this indeed is _attempted_ internally by the PDFBox code, it can only use heuristics there which sometimes fail. The only surprising part in your case is that these heuristics only fail for you _when sorting_. This _might_ be caused by space characters drawn at the problem position but out of order with the other characters, so that only sorting suddenly makes them play a role. But this is pure guesswork.